# Prestashop : loop on $product->save() method

Tags: php, save, prestashop, product

I'm creating a module for Prestashop and it need at each change on a product to recalculate the price.
This is my code :

```
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
    if ($this->context->controller->controller_type == 'front')
        return ;
    $id = $params['id_product'];
    $po = new Product($id);
    $cats = Product::getProductCategories($po->id);
    foreach ($cats as $cat)
    {   
        if ($cat == "49")
        {
            $ok = 1;
            break 1;
        }
        else
            $ok = 0;
    }
    if ($ok == 0)
        return 0;
    $po->price_tax_exc = $this->CalculatePrice($po);
    var_dump($po->price_tax_exc);
    $po->save(); // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
}
```

The problem is when i click on save, i will never go back to the product list on the admin.
When I replace save() by add() this is the same thing but it create product in a loop. So save() is in a loop and I don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this in at least two ways:

1.

```
protected $price_updated = false;

public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
   if ($this->price_updated)
      return null;
   .........
   if ($po->save())
      $this->price_updated = true;
}
```

2. Updating the value directly in the database (it would trigger you hook again). I haven't been able to find column inside product table which refers to `price_tax_exc`, I don't have much experience with prices :( Maybe `wholesale_price` ?