# Update overrided model for product in prestashop

Tags: model, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.6

I have a loop problem with my override of product model. I tried to implement this solution [Update product from a module in prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602713/update-product-from-a-module-in-prestashop). Here is the model (with an extra function for testing purpose) :

```
<?php
Class Product extends ProductCore
{
    // new field in product table
    public $design;
    public $fabric_front;
    public $fabric_back;
    public $fabric_front_border;
    public $fabric_back_border;

    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        // adding new fields in product's model definition
        self::$definition['fields']['design'] = array(
            'type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 
            'validate' => 'isCleanHtml',
        );
        self::$definition['fields']['fabric_front'] = array(
            'type' => self::TYPE_INT,
            'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt',
        );
        self::$definition['fields']['fabric_back'] = array(
            'type' => self::TYPE_INT,
            'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt',
        );
        self::$definition['fields']['fabric_front_border'] = array(
            'type' => self::TYPE_INT,
            'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt',
        );
        self::$definition['fields']['fabric_back_border'] = array(
            'type' => self::TYPE_INT,
            'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt',
        );

        // resume normal process
        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);
    }

    public function setDesign()
    {
        $sql = 'UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'product SET design="'.$this->design.'" WHERE id_product='.$this->id.';';
        if (!($update = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql)))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

And this is how I called the model in Hooks :

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
{
    $id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
    if (Validate::isLoadedObject($product = new Product($id_product))) {

        if (!empty($product) && isset($product->id)) 
            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'design_svg_img' => $product->design,
            ));

        return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/admin/build_design.tpl');

    } else 
        return $this->displayWarning($this->l('You must save this product before adding a design.'));
}

public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
    // get params from template
    $id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
    $svg_content = Tools::getValue('design_svg_upload');

    if (Validate::isLoadedObject($product = new Product($id_product))) {

        // attribute values to model members
        $product->design = $svg_content;

        if (!$product->save())
        // if (!$product->setDesign())
            return $this->displayWarning($this->l('Impossible to update product'));

    } else
        return $this->displayWarning($this->l('Product not found'));
}
```

The mechanics work, when I used the method $product->save() the data is inserted and retrieved from database but it also creates a infinite loop on the `hookActionProductUpdate()`.

But if I use my own function $product->setDesign() instead, everything is fine. 
So there is obviously something I missed. But I'm on it for 2 days without seeing it.

Comment: Because `$product->save()` triggers hook `actionProductUpdate` so `hookActionProductUpdate()` keeps looping.

Comment: So, it makes sense ! Thanks. But what would you advice to do it properly ?

Comment: I add this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732658/prestashop-loop-on-product-save-method

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Add extra field in product backoffice?

Comment: Your override is ok and in hook method you had it right by calling `$product->setDesign()`. Uncomment it and remove the line above it and its fine.

Comment: One more thing... You don't need to recreate `$product` object from `Tools::getValue('id_product')`. In hook method params you have `$params` array which holds two values - id of product that was saved `$params['id_product']` and product object itself `$params['product']`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I'll change my code in the 2 hooks so.